# SVG Foreign Object not displaying until changed

Tags: javascript, html, svg, namespaces

I am adding a foreign object to an svg element, which is a group with an id of 'all'. The foreign object does not appear when I do so.

However, if I use chrome's inspect element tools, and make any change at all to the foreign object in the elements view, the object appears.

```
var panel = document.createElement('div');
panel.className = 'panel';

var foreign = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'foreignobject');
foreign.setAttribute('width' , '202');
foreign.setAttribute('height', '122');
foreign.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0 0)');

all.appendChild(foreign);

foreign.appendChild(panel);
```

This seems very strange to me. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is a case sensitive language and the correct tag name is foreignObject

Comment: I'm interested to know why inspecting the element and editing it causes it to appear. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Because inspecting it causes the http parser to reparse it and the http parser magically fixes things to try to make life easier for developers.

Comment: Isn't the html parser used to parse initially though? What is different about the parsing of the html when I add it to the page, and the parsing when I edit the element using the developer tools?

Comment: No, document.createElementNS is a DOM call, it does not invoke the html parser.